# How to access the value of already checked radiobutton in second function call?

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events

I want to access the already selected radiobutton value in the second function call.

This is my code; can you please tell me where I am doing wrong? So when I click on checkbox I need to get already selected radio button value.

```
<input name="travel_type" id="arrival_1" type="radio" value="eclass_a" onClick="calculateTotal(this.value);checked="checked ">Arrivals $75
<input name="travel_type" id="dept_1" type="radio" value="eclass_d" onClick="calculateTotal(this.value); ">Departure $70
<input name="travel_type" id="pp_1" type="radio" value="eclass_p" onClick="calculateTotal(this.value);">Point to Point $70
<input name="travel_type" id="hourly_1" type="radio" value="eclass_h" onClick="calculateTotal(this.value);">Hourly $65

<input type="text" id="demo" name="demo" value="">

<b>Thsi is the second function call</b>

<input type="checkbox" style="border:none;" name="luggage_van" id="luggage_van" onClick="calculateTotal();getRadValue()" >Luggage Van
<input type="checkbox" style="border:none;" name="baby_seat" id="baby_seat" onClick="calculateTotal();getRadValue()" >Baby Seat
<input type="checkbox" style="border:none;" name="child_seat" id="child_seat" onClick="calculateTotal();getRadValue()">Child Seat
```

```
var globalvariable ;
function calculateTotal(id)
{
    globalvariable=document.getElementById('demo').value = id;
}
function getRadValue()
{
   var name = document.getElementById('demo').value = glovalvariable;
   alert(name);
}
```

So when I click on checkbox I need to get already selected radio button value.

Comment: Are you sure `glovalvariable` is not a typo?

Comment: attach it to `window` ex: `window.globalvariable`

Comment: did you mean when you click on second radio you need sum of all checked radio?

Comment: Where is `getRadValue()` being called?

Comment: No not sum of all radiobutton values, just already checked value i want, suppose if already checked value is e_class when user clicks on checkbox in second function call then also i need to get the e_class value. And i updated the getRadValue call. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second function `getRadValue()` isn't being called anywhere. Set it up:

`<input type="checkbox" style="border:none;" name="luggage_van" id="luggage_van" onClick="getRadValue();" >`

Fix your typo (glovalvariable vs globalvariable):

```
function getRadValue() {
    var name = document.getElementById('demo').value = globalvariable;
    alert(name);
}
```

Now when you click on the checkbox, you'll get an alert of your `globalvariable`.

Check for the existence of `id` in your first function:

```
function calculateTotal(id) {
    if (id) {
        globalvariable=document.getElementById('demo').value = id;
    }
    alert(globalvariable);
}
```

Comment: HI, I updated at checkbox code. When user clicks on checkbox that calculateTotal() and getRadValue() both functions will call and get the already checked radio button value.

Comment: Why do you need to run `calculateTotal()` with the checkbox? Also notice that this function takes an argument `id`. If you call it without supplying this parameter, it will return `undefined`.

Comment: Yes i am getting undefined,how can i pass id here? because i can not get id here. The reason for second call is i need to calculate some  total price when user checks check box.

Comment: Updated the answer. You don't have to pass in `id` the second time, as long as you check for the existence of it.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Please click the green tick mark next to the answer to accept it as correct.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.. am i tick green one correctly?